# C# Base 2 To Decimal

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

To convert decimal numbers to base 2, I use:

```
int base2 = 10;
Convert.ToString(base2, 2);
```

Output: 
`1010`

But how can I do the opposite? 
i.e:

Input : `1010`
Output : `10`

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
Convert.ToInt32("101010", 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do `Convert.ToInt32("1010",2);`